# Could Loki have used the Infinity Stones against Alioth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

Alioth was enchanted by Loki and Loki, but not without the sacrifice of the Loki we all mourn(*).

In the Void, all the magic Loki, Loki, Loki, perhaps the little green Loki, Loki, Loki, and perhaps the other Loki(s) from the rival group they fought in the basement... were available. Not in the TVA but in the Void. So, perhaps the Infinity Stones could be used as well. Loki (the main one, say) can use Infinity Stones with his bare hands, so perhaps he could use the 6 at the same time.

There were lots and lots of Infinity Stones stored in a little drawer in the first episode, and there was Mobius who escaped from the Void using a tempad.

A perhaps useful reasoning would be:

1. Go to the tempad, back to the offices.
2. Seek the Infinity Stones in the drawer. Take 6 of them, distinct.
3. Keep the tempad in the suit, as Sylvie (Loki) did, and also keep the stones, look for a pruning rod or a guard who has one, and get pruned, back to the void with the 6 Infinity Stones to use against Alioth.

Is there any reason (an in-universe explanation, and nothing like Wanda's "the director did not know who was Mephisto") why Loki (the main one) did not consider this (e.g. was it proven that infinity stones would not be useful against Alioth)?

(*) *yes, that was a very sad night to me*.

Comment: "Loki (the main one, say) can use Infinity Stones with bare hands"  — can he? I  don't think we ever see that happen. He escapes holding the Tesseract, but as we saw in *Infinity War*, that's some sort of container for the Space Stone.

Comment: Or... perhaps assembling the gauntlet in the same TVA office, then keeping it, pruning himself into the void again, and then beating Alioth with the gauntlet.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the Infinity Stones could have been used for the reasons you outline, magic only doesn’t work at the TVA. They didn’t go to get them because once they had the means to getting them they had a better plan. Morbius, Sylvie and the TemPad only turned up later on. At that point Sylvie comes up with a plan that’s most likely a lot better and certainly less convoluted than trying to get the Infinity Stones.

> **Loki:** Okay, so, um, how do we get past the guard dog?
>
> **Sylvie:** I'm gonna enchant it.
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 6, “Journey into Mystery”</sub>

Note that the theme of the episode and running through the season is how powerful Lokis are. He’s moved past the need for such trivial things as Infinity Stones and is learning to rely on himself, and others.

Note that in the comics Infinity Stones [only work in the universe they come from](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184469/58193). If this holds true for the MCU then it is possible that the Infinity Stones wouldn’t actually work at all at the Void. Also consider that these stones are ones from pruned timelines so it could even be that they won’t work as their timeline has been erased.

Comment: You'd need the infinity stones for *that particular universe*.

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to be in a specific universe for the infinity stones to work
the avengers retrieved a stone from six different timelines and their plan worked just fine.
Its a valid idea, but i have 2 doubts.
One is that loki would be obliterated by all six stones used at once. The hulks arm was burned useless after he did the snap. And loki got his ass handed to him by the hulk

TWO ALIOTH feeds on matter and energy, my intuition tells me you'd be feeding him by blasting him with the power of the gauntlet

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence to support your theories?